# Can an involute gear profile be modeled with a Bézier curve?

Tags: plane-curves, bezier-curve

In the context of a game, I want to draw gears. The most common curves available on the platforms I'm using are third degree Bézier curves.

Is there an exact representation of the [involute gear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involute_gear) using only Bézier curves ?

Comment: Exact? No. But within screen resolution of your game, yes.

Comment: What is the nature of this curve ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  From [this paper](http://web.mit.edu/harishm/www/papers/involuteEWC.pdf) that discusses approximating an involute curve using a 4th degree Bezier:

> The circle involute curves are by definition transcendental and cannot be expressed by algebraic equations

Comment: Thanks for the link. It looks close enough for me.

Answer (score 3):

While researching gear profile approximations, I came across this SE.

I wanted to add that I found this site: http://www.arc.id.au/GearDrawing.html which describes the usage of cubic (3rd degree) bezier curves about halfway down.

I know this is an old post, just thought I'd update some more relevant information because the answer was given for 4th order only.  That paper is referenced heavily within the site.